# Do two active high signals cancel each other?

Tags: signal, electrical

A tp4056's temp pin is pulled HIGH, so it disables the chip. I accidentally fed a high signal into that same pin and it enabled the chip again!, which has to mean the signal went LOW. Are these two high signals cancelling each other? or is something else happening?

Answer: So I figured it out. First of all **HIGH HIGH != LOW**(its not math). Secondly, the pull-up is not at fault either. My signal when HIGH is 3.60v and when LOW is 1.23v, also my Vin is 4.73v (laptop). As the datasheet mentions, "If TEMP pin’s voltage is below 45% or above 80% of supply voltage VIN". **1.23 of 4.73 is 26%** (which is below 45%, so the chip turns off) and **3.60 of 4.73 is 76%~** (which is just ever so slightly below the 80% threshold) that's why when signal is HIGH the chip remains on.

Comment: Something else is happening.

Comment: Can you explain what? The chip is working perfectly btw

Comment: No I can't explain it - something else is happening because, your description of what you did doesn't allow for the possibility for the signals to cancel hence....

Comment: The temp pin has an internal timer of 150ms for signal detection. So you have different behaviour when applying a high signal, depending on how long the signal is applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [datasheet.](https://www.sunrom.com/get/109600)

> TEMP(Pin 1) :Temperature Sense Input Connecting TEMP pin to NTC thermistor’s output in Lithium ion battery pack. If TEMP pin’s voltage is below 45% or above 80% of supply voltage VIN for more than 0.15S, this means that battery’s temperature is too high or too low, charging is suspended. The temperature sense function can be disabled by grounding the TEMP pin.

The "Temp" pin isn't an "active high."  It is "low to disable temperature sense" and outside of that it is an analog value that represents the temperature of the battery pack.  If you "pulled it high" then you made the the TP4056 think the temperature changed.

---

If you want to suspend charging, you should use the "chip enable" input, which is also described in the datasheet.

Pull "chip enable" low to suspend operation of the chip.

Comment: If I pull it HIGH the chip thinks the battery temperature is high and charging is suspended (Which I want) but I thought I'd have to set the signal low again from my microcontroller to enable the charger again but no, I get the pin high and the chip gets enabled. This part is confusing me.

Comment: Im using those little blue tp4056 modules. I know about the CE pin but the board is layed out in such a way that the pin is tied to vcc underneath the chip and the IT IS A HEATSINK PAD FOR THE CHIP. Just a pain, thats why i simply cut the temp pin trace which was grounded also but was easier to disable and feed my own signal.

Comment: @FarazAhmed If you set it high and then you set it high, it's still high. The second one *doesn't change anything*.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. First of all its not related to the pull-up. My signal when HIGH is 3.60v and when LOW is 1.23v, also my Vin is 4.73v (laptop). As the datasheet mentions, "If TEMP pin’s voltage is **below 45% or above 80% of supply voltage VIN**". 1.23 of 4.73 is 26% (which is below 45% and the chip turns off) and 3.60 of 4.73 is 76%~ (which is just even so slightly below the 80% threshold) that's why when HIGH the chip remains on.
After a lot of research, **HIGH HIGH != LOW**

Comment: Rather than Answer your own question, please can you edit this information into your question. Thanks.